# Is there a research-based book that discusses feline social interactions and cues?

Tags: behavior, cats

Cats have some surprisingly subtle nuances in the ways that they express themselves.  From the way they hold their tail, to how they make eye contact, or even [how loudly they meow](http://www.thecatsite.com/a/the-silent-meow), there are a wide variety of means of communication.

Is there a research-based book anyone could recommend that explains cat social interactions and communication in depth?

Answer (score 2):

The book I prefer is the *[Manual of Clinical Behavioral Medicine For Dogs and Cats](https://www.elsevier.com/books/manual-of-clinical-behavioral-medicine-for-dogs-and-cats/overall/978-0-323-00890-7)* by Karen L. Overall. It covers a large range of behavioral issues for both species, describes what is normal both for interacting with other animals and humans, documents abnormal/undesirable behavior and provides information and advice on correcting, and finally, provides worksheets to help narrow down issues.

In general, I find it reliable and clear with pictures, charts, and decent structure. It could probably do with a slightly better layout, but it's not too bad and there is plenty of references and citations to studies and further sources of reading. So, generally, I like it. :)